# Access Violation: run through array from bmp image

Tags: c

I have a bmp image that I transform into a bi-dimensional array. That work fine.
But I need to compare the color of one pixel (coordonate (i,j)) with its neighbors (8 pixels).
If one or more have the same color, I compare them with its other neighbors and....
So I plan to use a recursive function.

The code:

```
void verifIdPoint (int TG[NBLIG][NBCOL], int T[NBLIG][NBCOL], short int Tpassage[NBLIG][NBCOL], int i, int j)
{
int u, v;

//printf ("saisie: %d   %d \n", i, j);

//system("pause");

for (u=i-1; u<=i+1; u++)
{
    for(v=j-1; v<=j+1; v++)
    {
               
        if(u>0 || v>0 || u<NBLIG || v<NBCOL)
        {
            if (TG[u][v] == TG[i][j])
            {
                tableauImgIntermediaire (TG, T, i, j);
                //printf ("TG[%d][%d]===== TG[%d][%d]\n", u, v, i, j);
                
                if (u<=0 || v<=0 || u>=NBLIG || v>=NBCOL)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Tpassage[u][v] == 0)
                    {
                    
                       printf ("Passage: u v T   %d %d %d \n", u, v, Tpassage[u][v]);
                       Tpassage[u][v] = 1;
                       verifIdPoint (TG, T, Tpassage, u, v);
                    }
                }        
            } 
        }                
    }               
}
}
```

This code works with an image with just a part of it with the same color (like a grey circle in the middle).
But when the color is like a stick which go from (0,0) to (300,200), I have "access violation (segment fault)" error...

The image size is 300x200.
I think, that's because i'm trying to access to a part of my array which is not allocated.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your bounds.

```
if(u>0 || v>0 || u<NBLIG || v<NBCOL)
```

will evaluate to true for (0,0) and (NBLIG, NBCOL). (And (-1,-1))

```
if( (u >= 0 && u < NBLIG) && (v >= 0 && v < NBCOL) )
```

is probably more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Your second bounds check appears to be redundant, but if you want to keep it, you need to make sure the value is strictly less than the max.

Comment: Those original `if`s are nasty. But in the for-loop, `u` and `v` iterate *from* `u=i-1` *to* `u<=i+1`. While there is no explanation for what arguments `i` and `j` do, context suggests they are what everyone else calls `x` and `y`. In that case, (1) the check needs to be `if u>=1` (and mirrored for 'width-1'), but (2) this particular check is *not* necessary (that is, if the input is correct). +1, though, for noticing these odd tests mess up what should have been a simple job.

Comment: Well, here is how I understand it: The function is given (`i`,`j`), then `u`,`v` iterate, and then the bounds-checking occurs.

So if `i = j = 0`, `u` and `v` will range from -1 to 1. Since I'm assuming the edges should be tested (e.g. (0, 1) , (1, 0)), `u` and `v` should be allowed to take those values, instead of giving them an extra border.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers ! Appreciate :)
But I think that i don't go in the right direction.
What do you think about a flood fill algorithm ?

I'm trying a code like that:

```
 void fill(int TG[NBLIG][NBCOL], int i, int j, int couleurCible)
 {
     if (TG[i][j] == couleurCible)
     {
        TG[i][j] = couleurCible + 50;
        remplissage (TG[i][j+1], i, j, couleurCible);
        remplissage (TG[i][j-1], i, j, couleurCible);
        remplissage (TG[i+1][j], i, j, couleurCible);
        remplissage (TG[i-1][j], i, j, couleurCible);

     }
 }
```

With couleurCible the color of my first pixel (i,j).

Thanks !
Best Regards